# Selecting a list of all non-distinct users who fit a criteria SQL

Tags: sql

I have a large list of people, their emails and subscription status - Active, Cancelled or Trial.

Some people cancel their subscription, but activate again and this creates a new record. This leaves me with a list of people with both a cancelled and active subscription.

I would like to contact all people with a cancelled subscription, but if I were to write a simple query it won't check if the same email has a different subscription that is active.

Here's a quick example of what I mean:

```
client_email ; subscription_status
john@gmail.com - Cancelled
john@gmail.com - Active
fred@gmail.com - Cancelled
fred@gmail.com - Cancelled
terry@gmail.com - Active
lilly@gmail.com - Cancelled
```

I want to be able to return fred@gmail.com and lilly@gmail.com.

All I have been able to do so far is create a list of all accounts that have more than one record:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions
WHERE customers_email
IN (
  SELECT customers_email
  FROM subscriptions
  GROUP BY customers_email
  HAVING COUNT( customers_email ) >1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT customers_email
FROM subscriptions
group by customers_email
having min(subscription_status)='Cancelled' and max(subscription_status)='Cancelled'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to find all emails where a record does NOT EXIST in the subscriptions table with the same email and subscription_status = 'Active'....

which translates to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.customers_email
FROM subscriptions s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM subscriptions s2 
    WHERE s2.customers_email = s.customers_email AND s2.subscription_status = 'Active')
```